# Why am I getting strange values for integer in this example of derived class (C++)

Tags: c++

I was given a task to write an example of derived class. But In my program, something strange is happening with the roll numbers.

Also, when this program is compiled in g++.

When I used `char []` and `gets()` to store the strings and input values into them, it didn't allow me to enter the value for `collname`.

When I use `string` and `cin`, I get some strange values while asking for marks.(Check the attached image).

[image]

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

class uni
{
    private:
    int rollno[100], i, flag;
    int intermarks[100];;
    int theorymarks[100];
    void settheorymarks();

    protected:
    int numstud;
    void setintermarks();
    void issurno();
    
    public:
    void prepres();
    void showres(string collname);

};

class college : public uni
{
    private:
    string collname;
    public:
    college(int N)
    {
        numstud = N;
        issurno();
    }
    void enter_marks();
    void disp();
};

void uni::issurno()
{
    for (i = 0; i < numstud; i++)
        rollno[i] = 1024+i;
    cout << "Roll numbers issued!" << endl;
}

void uni::settheorymarks()
{
    cout << "Enter theory marks for: " << endl ;
    for(i = 0; i < numstud; i++)
    {
        cout << i+1 << ".) Roll number: " << rollno << "  : ";
        cin >> theorymarks[i];
    }
    cout << endl << endl << "Theory marks recorded!" << endl;
}

void uni::setintermarks()
{
    cout << "Enter inter marks for: " << endl ;
    for(i = 0; i < numstud; i++)
    {
        cout << i+1 << ".) Roll number: " << rollno << "  : ";
        cin >> intermarks[i];
    }
    cout << endl << endl << "Internal marks recorded!" << endl;
}

void uni::prepres()
{
    settheorymarks();
}

void uni::showres(string colnam)
{
    cout << "College: " << colnam << endl;
    cout << "__________________________Result___________________________" << endl;
    cout << "s. No.\tRoll no\tInternal\tTheory" << endl;
    for(i = 0; i < numstud; i++)
        cout << i+1 << "\t" << rollno[i] << '\t' << intermarks[i] << "\t" << theorymarks[i] << endl;
    cout << endl << "End of result!" << endl;
}

void college::disp()
{
    showres(collname);
}

void college::enter_marks()
{
    cout << "Enter the college name: ";
    cin >> collname;
    setintermarks();
    prepres();
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Enter number of stufents: ";
    cin >> n;
    college c(n);
    c.enter_marks();
    c.disp();
    return 0;
}
```

I feel that I've made a stupid mistake somewhere.
PS: In school, I was forced to use turbo C++ (One of the oldest compilers).

Comment: The offending statement is `cout << i+1 << ".) Roll number: " << rollno << "  : ";`.     `rollno` is an array of `int` so is converted to a pointer (to its first element).  `cout` then outputs that element.     Some *other* programming languages, if your output an array, will output elements of that array - C++ does not behave like that.     If you want to manipulate or output an element of `rollno` use the syntax (say) `rollno[i]`.   If you want to output the whole array, write a loop that outputs elements one at a time.

Comment: Yes, I felt that I am doing something vey stupid. probably gonna delete the question in some time. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I'm sorry to say that but your programming style is aweful. I strongly suggest to rewrite your entire program, but before you do, please read some articles/tutorials about object oriented programming and about "no goes". In short words, "less is more" but "less isn't always the best".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just forget the `[i]` after `rollno` in the two lines like:

```
 cout << i+1 << ".) Roll number: " << rollno[i] << "  : ";
```

---

There are a few other things I would ask you to improve if I was your supervisor/teacher:

- always use expressive variable and method names. Avoid any abbreviations.
- why is there the arbitray offset of 1024 in rollno? If this is just "obfuscation" remove it...
- Unclear: why is setintermarks called inside enter_marks but settheorymarks in prepres ?
- typo in "stufents"